# Distribution of a sample of uniformly distributed points in the 2D

Tags: distributions, uniform-distribution, truncation

Let there be a rectangle in the plane and a set of points distributed in the rectangle by a uniform distribution. I select a random point on the top and right border and draw the red line. The blue triangle is formed after drawing the line. I would like to know if the distribution of points inside the blue triangle is still uniform (with different parameters)? Or it is changed to something else?

[image]

Comment: I like your picture because it answers the question: when you paint a card uniformly blue, and cut off a triangular piece of that card, is the piece also uniformly blue?

Comment: @whuber I come with background of computer science and not very good at statistics. I'm sorry if the question is silly or too obvious but it is difficult to me.

Comment: In the continuous setting, a uniform distribution over a region is one for which the probability density function is constant in the region (and zero outside of the region). If you take that constant pdf and divide it by the probability of being in the blue region (and set it to zero outside the blue region), you get the conditional distribution of the blue region, which is still constant in the blue region (and zero outside of it).

Comment: @user469053 Ok, Is the distribution of blue region is uniform?

Comment: Yes, because it satisfies the condition that its pdf is constant in the blue region and zero outside of it, which is what it means for a continuous random variable to be uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture is very nice.  The evenness of the blue color is an accurate visual metaphor for the evenness of the probability represented by the color.  A uniform distribution has perfectly even probability, so even when you cut out ("truncate") a piece of the sample space, the probability remains even--and therefore is uniform.

---

You seem to want a rigorous solution, too, so here goes.  We need two definitions: uniform probability and truncation.  After that, the demonstration is short and simple.

#### Uniform probability

In any space $S$ where we can measure the "area" or, more generally, the "size" $|\mathcal R|$ of regions $\mathcal R\subset S,$ a probability distribution $\mathbb P$ defined on $S$ is said to be *uniform* when probabilities are proportional to size.  Because the probability of $S$ itself must be $1,$ we deduce

$$\mathbb{P}(\mathcal R) = \frac{|\mathcal R|}{|\mathcal S|}.$$

(Notice this implies $S$ has finite size!)

#### Truncation

Your act of slicing off a portion of the rectangle $S$ amounts to fixing a subregion $\mathcal T\subset S$ (the triangle).  Doing that is called *truncation* (from the Latin for "cutting off").  No matter what the original probability distribution might have been (uniform or not), it determines a new probability distribution on $\mathcal T:$ all you have to do is *normalize* the original one to make the total probability of $\mathcal T$ equal to $1.$  Therefore, when $\mathcal R \subset \mathcal T,$ the new probability is

$$\mathbb{P}_{\mathcal T}(\mathcal R) = \frac{\mathbb P(\mathcal R)}{\mathbb P(\mathcal T)}.$$

(Notice this can be defined only when $\mathcal T$ has nonzero probability!)

#### Solution

With these definitions in place, the solution amounts to a basic fact of arithmetic.  When $\mathbb P$ is uniform and $\mathcal R\subset \mathcal T,$ we plug the first equation (uniform probability) into the second (truncation) to find

$$\mathbb{P}_{\mathcal T}(\mathcal R) =  \frac{\mathbb P(\mathcal R)}{\mathbb P(\mathcal T)} = \frac{|\mathcal R|/|\mathcal S|}{|\mathcal T|/|\mathcal S|} = \frac{|\mathcal R|}{|\mathcal T|},$$

because the common nonzero factors of $1/|S|$ in numerator and denominator cancel.  But the resulting formula is *exactly* the uniform distribution on $\mathcal T,$ which is what we needed to show.